# Limit of $\left(e^2 \frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{(1+x²)^{1/x²}}\right)^{1/x}$ when $x\to0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have been struggling with this limit for a while:

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \left(e^2 \frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{(1+x²)^{1/x²}}\right)^{1/x}
$$

I suspect I have to use the $\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$ limit and probably the L'Hopital's rule, but I don't know how to start.

Thank you so much for any kind of help, just to get me started

Comment: Not always is a good idea to use complete fraction symbol for powers, in particular when the expression is messy. I thinkl it must be clear the exponent of the denominator above is $\;1/x^2\;$ , as it looked, and still looks a little, like $\;1/x\;$ .

Comment: $a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$ might help you.

Answer (score 4):

For $x\to 0^+$, $(1+x)^{1/x}\to e$ and $(1+x^2)^{1/x^2}\to e$ and then

$$\left(e^2 \frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{(1+x^2)^{1/x^2}}\right)^{1/x}\sim e^{2/x}\to \infty$$

For $x\to 0^-$ 
$$\left(e^2 \frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{(1+x^2)^{1/x^2}}\right)^{1/x}\sim e^{2/x}\to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

We can try arithmetic of limits. Since

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\left(1+f(x)\right)^{1/f(x)}=e\;,\;\;\text{for any function such that}\;\;\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$$

we have that

$$\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to0}(1+x^2)^{1/x^2}=e$$

so there exists *a right neighborhood* of zero, $\;I_\epsilon:=(0,\epsilon)\;$ such that for any $\;x\in I_\epsilon$:

$$0.9<\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{(1+x^2)^{1/x^2}}<1.1$$ , and thus

$$ (e^2\cdot0.9)^{1/x}\le\left(e^2 \frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{(1+x²)^{1/x²}}\right)^{1/x}\le(e^2\cdot1.1)^{1/x}$$

and by the squeeze theorem the limit is $\;+\infty\;$, and thus *the* limit doesn't exist finitely (I think from the left it is zero nd thus the limit doesn't exist at all)